# Store that I made is not working in python

Tags: python

I have this code that I made and it won't work when I run the code. I am trying to make a sword shop but when I go and try and buy the sword it exits the shop and says I don't have enough money. There is not enough code here to test the code because I have classes and a few defines. If you want the rest of the code just ask. This is my code. Sorry that my title kind of sucks. If you want the rest of the code I put the code on pastepin.com. Here is the link. https://pastebin.com/eXVri8nx

```
    question = input("What would you like?")

    if question.lower().strip() == 'Rusty Sword':
        if player.gold >= 10:
            print("")
            question = input("Are you sure you want to purchase this item?")

            if question.lower().strip() == 'yes':
                player.gold = player.gold - 10
                print("You now own a Rusty Sword!")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("You have " + player.gold + " gold left")
                time.sleep(2)
                question = input("Would you like to equip this sword?")

                if question.lower().strip() == 'yes':
                    player.sword = "Rusty Sword"
                    print("You now have the " + player.sword + " Eqquiped")

                if question.lower().strip() == 'no':
                    print("You have the " + player.sword + " Eqquiped")
                    # SOMETHING GOES HERE

            if question.lower().strip() == 'no':
                Store()

    else:
        print("You do not have enough money.")
        Store()
```

If anyone could help me that would be great! Thanks for reading.

Comment: `player.gold` is probably a string where it should be an integer. And if it's an integer, the `print("You have " + player.gold + " gold left")` statement won't work

Comment: btw you seem to have `class Store():` **and** `def Store():`. Perhaps the function should be called something different.

Comment: btw Your `Store()` function is calling itself. That's recursion and not a good idea in this case. Perhaps you should investigate loops.

Comment: Why can't I do a integer?

Comment: @khuynh: btw the code as posted is part of a function. That's why the formatting looks off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "Rusty Sword" to "rusty sword"...

Comment: this could have been a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You set the input to all lower case with `lower()`, yet you have upper case in your query.

```
if question.lower().strip() == 'Rusty Sword':
```

Change it to:

```
if question.lower().strip() == 'rusty sword':
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this is wrong:

```
if question.lower().strip() == 'Rusty Sword':
```

This is never going to be true since you are comparing to a non lower case string.
Perhaps you meant:

```
if question.lower().strip() == 'rusty sword':
```